# Raising an ActiveRecord error on RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way of doing a find_by_x that raises an exception if the record is not found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

added "!" at the end:

```
User.find_by_name "a" => return nil

User.find_by_name! "a" => raise error
```